# what are inheritable attributes in websphere liberty serevr.xml

Tags: websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I was going through the documentation for how to configure websphere liberty (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_setup_vars.html) and found the following

```
Override inheritable attributes in the configuration

You can override the default values of inheritable attributes in the configuration. 
The inheritable attributes are listed on the page with an Inherits type. For example,
the onError attribute is one of inheritable attributes. You can define a variable 
name for the onError attribute globally by either setting it in the bootstrap.properties
or server.xml file with a variable element. If the same variable name is specified in 
both files, the value in the server.xml file is used. If the attribute is not explicitly 
set in either of two files, it uses the default value. If an invalid value is set to the
inheritable attribute, the attribute value falls back to the global value defined in 
bootstrap.properties or server.xml file or the default value if not defined at the 
global level.
```

What are the inheritable attributes referred to here? I am not able to find any document that defines these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a mistake in the documentation. There is no concept of "inheritable" attributes in Liberty configuration.

I think what this is trying to describe is a certain set of attributes that can be specified in bootstrap.properties, server.xml as a variable, or in server.xml as configuration. This mostly applies to the cases listed -- onError and logging properties.

For example, if you want to specify the maximum number of log files to keep, you could set the following in bootstrap.properties:

```
com.ibm.ws.logging.max.files=5
```

Or you could use this in server.xml:

```
<variable name="com.ibm.ws.logging.max.files" value="5"/>
```

Or you could configure this in server.xml:

```
<logging maxFiles="5"/>
```

They all have the same effect (with the small caveat that the ones in server.xml do not take effect until after the configuration has been processed, so if you're setting a trace string to debug startup configuration processing you would want it to be in bootstrap.properties.) If the value is specified multiple ways, the configured value in server.xml takes precedence over the variable value from server.xml and the variable value takes precedence over the bootstrap.properties value.